# Why I can't create FK in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, key

I have this two tables:

1) UsersTable:

```
userID:  PK,  int,  notnull
username:  nvarchar(MAX),  notnull
password:  nvarchar(MAX),  notnull
Roles:  int,  notnull
```

2) UserRoles:

```
ID_Roles:  PK,  int,  notnull
Role:  nvarchar(MAX),  notnull
```

Now I whant to put FK (foreign key) in UserTable where ID of FK is ID_Roles, and I get this error:

'UserRoles' table saved successfully
'UsersTable' table
- Unable to create relationship 'FK_UsersTable_UserRoles'.
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_UsersTable_UserRole". The conflict occurred in database "userDb", table "dbo.UserRole", column 'ID_Roles'.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Do you have values in UsersTable?

Comment: yes I have some values in UsersTable, is this a mistake

Comment: If the values in the column Roles don't match the values in the table UserRoles it's a mistake. and the realationship is not match and cannot be created

Answer (score 3):

If you have data in User table and records for Roles field in this table is different from the values present in UserRoles table then you will receive this error.
   So please make sure data present in User table for Roles field have values present in UserRoles table.